# Differences between Script & Code behind?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

Please let me ask something. I just confused for what is the difference of javascript, JQuery and code behind attributes.
for example : 
ASPX

```
<tbody id="toggleSup" runat="server">
```

C#

```
toggleSup.Visible = false;
```

--------------------------------------- OR ---------------------------

C#

```
CallScript((string)(Session["toggle"])); 

private void CallScript(string str)
    {
        string scriptx = "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='javascript'>";
        scriptx += "toggle('" + str + "');";
        scriptx += "</script>";

        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "scriptx", scriptx, false);
    }
```

Script

```
function toggle(para1) {           
        if (para1 == 0) {
            $('#toggleSup').hide();
        }
        else {
            $('#togglePO').hide();
        }
    }
```

for these two difference things, most of the developers use script. Why? Actually C# code is only one row. different thing is if I use script, no need to use runat="server" but if I used code behind, need to use runat = "server". So I think there may be definately have advantages. Please explain me, if possible...

Thanks

Comment: Note: JQuery *is* JavaScript. For purposes of your question there is no need to distinguish between the two.

Comment: yes. I mean differences between Javascript/ JQuery and Code behind. Sorry for not cleared question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you say `toggleSup.Visible = false;` in your C#, then the toggleSup does not even get rendered to the DOM.  Meaning it's not on the page at all.  If you want to make that element visible from some action on the page, then you have to make a round trip to the server and re-render all (postback) or part (ajax) of the page.

Alternatively, if you allow the `toggleSub` control to be manipulated from JavaScript (jQuery in this case), then it's part of the DOM and can be acted upon in response to other events on the page.  Mainly, this means that the client browser can do things without asking the server for more HTML.

So, the C# method looks simpler to code, but the jQuery method is more flexible if you need a rich client-side experience.

Comment: wow! really liked answer! so sometimes i got the error when I use jquery but i dun know why. Please check my question, I used script and call from C# but actually didn't work. If i changed these script to document.ready. It's pretty work... why?

Comment: Hmm, try this...  change this line `scriptx += "toggle('" + str + "');";` to this: `scriptx += "$(document).ready(function() { toggle('" + str + "') });";`.  I suspect that your toggle method is rendered after your clientscriptblock and so `toggle()` isn't always available when it's called.

Comment: :) still cannot, actually I called script like this
'protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session["toggle"] = "1";

            CallScript((string)(Session["toggle"]));     

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
}}' from page_Load

Answer (score 1):

When using "script", the browser performs the work.  With runat server, then the browser must either get/post a HTTP request or do "AJAX" to the server.

Using "script" is much faster and is easier to maintain state.

Comment: Depends heavily on the intention. Your assuming that this is a post back, rather than just the initial page load. If we are primarily concerned with the latter, than the server-side script is more efficient.

Comment: @Richard Schneider
Thanks for your answer. but if i used script, still need to call from code behind, rite? private voide something like this...

Answer (score 1):

In simple words Java Script and JQuery code runs on the client browser whereas C# code runs on the server.